# Updating a ImageStream from Dockerhub Registry in Openshift

Tags: docker, containers, openshift

I have a template that defines a object "ImageStream":

```
{
      "apiVersion":"v1",
      "kind": "ImageStream",
      "metadata": {
        "name": "${APPLICATION_NAME}-img",
        "labels": {
          "app": "${APPLICATION_NAME}"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "tags": [
          {
            "name": "latest",
            "from": {
              "kind": "DockerImage",
              "name": "rlanhellas/${APPLICATION_NAME}"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

So, after created I got the image inside openshift registry, the `oc get is` command return this:

```
$ oc get is
NAME                   IMAGE REPOSITORY                                                                                                   TAGS      UPDATED
safepark-netcore-img   default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps.us-east-2.starter.openshift-online.com/safepark/safepark-netcore-img   latest    About an hour ago
```

My original image within dockerhub and my pipeline tool always update the `latest` tag in dockerhub. But the ImageStream in openshift is not updated, so I got always a old version of my image in openshift and a new build is never triggered because the openshift image is not updated.

How can I "link" the ImageStream in OpenShift to my Dockerhub image and ensure that updated image in dockerhub will update the image in openshift ?

**Important:** I'm using Openshift Online with Free Plan.

Comment: You can't link them in a fully automated way so the change is reflected immediately. Use `oc import-image` command to trigger an update to the image stream so it uses the very latest.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I will add this command to my pipeline

Answer (score 2):

If you want an image to automatically sync from one registry to your openshift registry, you can use `importPolicy` to achieve this.

The [OpenShift 3.11 documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/managing_images.html#importing-tag-and-image-metadata) explains the `importPolicy` functionality.

Set `importPolicy` to `true` to automatically sync the image.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ImageStream
metadata:
  name: ruby
spec:
  tags:
  - from:
      kind: DockerImage
      name: openshift/ruby-20-centos7
    name: latest
    importPolicy:
      scheduled: true
    apiVersion: v1
kind: ImageStream
metadata:
  name: ruby
spec:
  tags:
  - from:
      kind: DockerImage
      name: openshift/ruby-20-centos7
    name: latest
    importPolicy:
      scheduled: true
```

Comment: Good, I will try and return here

Comment: @RonaldoLanhellas So? Did it work? It's been two years and you haven't reported back or accepted this as the solution.